# How to split dates with VB in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Facing such a problem when hadling with excels again...

I have an excel table with such cloumns

```
People    Date
-------------------------
A         01/01/2013 - 05/01/2013
B         03/05/2013
C         08/06/2013
```

What I want to produce (For example A)

```
People    Individual Date
-------------------------
A         01/01/2013  
A         02/01/2013  
A         03/01/2013  
A         04/01/2013  
A         05/01/2013
```

The year will be constant at 2013 and month are more or less kept constant as well.

Can someone give idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you only want values for people with date ranges or all values?

Comment: Also, do you want to write the values to another excel table or just have as a variable?

Comment: Hi @bendataclear I want only people with dates, and it's best to be put in another worksheet at the same workbook

Comment: And forget to mention "01/01/2013 - 05/01/2013" is represented as a single cell in a form of String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ExpandDates()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vaDates As Variant
    Dim rNext As Range

    'Loop through the cells that contain dates or date ranges
    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("B2:B4").Cells

        'If there's a space, hyphen, space in the cell, it's a date range
        If InStr(1, rCell.Value, " - ") > 0 Then

            'Split the cell contents on space, hyphen, space
            vaDates = Split(rCell.Value, " - ")

            'Loop through the days of the range of dates
            For i = CDate(vaDates(0)) To CDate(vaDates(1))

                'Find the next blank cell in column E to record the results
                Set rNext = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

                'Write column A to column E
                rNext.Value = rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                'Create a new date in column B using the month that the loop is currently processing
                rNext.Offset(0, 1).Value = CDate(i)
            Next i

        'If no hyphen, it's just a date, so create one line in column E
        Else
            Set rNext = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            rNext.Value = rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            rNext.Offset(0, 1).Value = rCell.Value
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sir thanks so much for your help! But your solution seems only produces "A 01/01/2013" for the first row of data.

Comment: Hi Dick I just modified a bit in the for loop to use days as looper but not months and its working perfectly fine, thanks!

Comment: Ah, I'm American and so read your dates as m/d/yyyy, but you meant d/m/yyyy. Sorry about that. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Updated to iterate through days instead of months.

Answer (score 0):

Theory: Check the length of the cell.  If the cell is longer than 10 characters, use the SPLIT function to get the 2 dates.  Set the months equal to a variable, and do a loop based on those months to calculate the dates between them.  You would probably store those dates in an array.  Then write the array to the spreadsheet and move to the next cell to start the process over.

EDIT:

```
Sub prSplit()

    If len(ActiveCell.Value) > 10 Then

    Dim arr() As String

    arr = Trim(Split(ActiveCell.Value, "-"))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        MsgBox arr(i)
    Next

    End If
End Sub
```

You can start with this and tweak the code until you get it.  I just don't have the time to do the whole thing.  Sorry.  :o(

Comment: Hi I'm really new to VB, can provide me with a proto or somewhere I can learn about those things? With much thanks!

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out and feedback to you once I get it

Comment: Forgot to add the Len statement.  I fixed that above.  Sorry.  :o(